# Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed

Tags: bibtex, makeindex, texify, miktex2.9

This seems to be a well known problem, but I'm afraid I couldn't find a solution. I've used latex/miktex for years, but when I tried to compile a document yesterday, I got the error message

> ```
> Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed. 
>
> The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
>
> C:/Users/XXXXX/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/texify.log
>
> You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
> ```

The log file contains the following:

```
texify - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
```

The code runs fine with `pdfLatex`, but if I use `pdflateX+MakeIndex+BibTex`, it won't compile any more. Even my test code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{phreport}

\begin{document}

hello! \cite{99mich}

\bibliography{reportbib}

\end{document}
```

doesn't work. I tried re-installing `MikTex` (w/o success), and tried to update (admin) my packages, which doesn't work:

> ```
>   Sorry, but something went wrong: The executed process did not succeed. 
>
>   fileName = 'C:\Program Files\MikTex2.9\miktex\bin\x64xinitexmf.exe"
>
>   arguments="--update-fndb --verbose--admin", exitCode="1"
> ```

Maybe that's the problem? I would be really thankful for any help. My last years with `miktex` went without problems and I don't know where to tackle this fundamental problem.

Many thanks!
Best, CBo

Comment: There is a backslash missing in `\x64xinitexmf.exe`. But I have no idea why texify tries to update the FNDB. You could try to update it externally (in miktex-settings, user and admin version) My general advice is: Don't use texify. It fails often, and when it fails it is difficult to debug. Use latexmk or arara instead.

Comment: I have this problem constantly with this great editor. I solve every time deleting the old results of building (`.synctex`, `.pdf`, ...). I hope that my suggest solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem where running with BibTex would throw this error, and found that the issue was within the .bib file that I had. Specifically, there was one citation with an accidental space in the reference name and another that was a duplicate. There was some info about which citation was problematic directly above the error message.

Anyways, so I guess try and make sure that all the entries in your .bib file are properly formatted.

I also found that this error occurs if I have the final pdf document open in adobe reader while compiling.

Comment: There really isn't any reason to think this is the OP's problem, though, is there?

Comment: I think there is, because OP says "The code runs fine with pdfLatex, but if I use pdflateX+MakeIndex+BibTex, it won't compile any more.", which to me implies that there is something wrong with how MikTex is handling the bibliography.

Comment: It is trying to update the filename database. The question is: why?

Answer (score 1):

Just solved that problem with "Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed." message after update. I had a spelling bug within \cite{}, I mistakenly used a capital letter ('LV2009') to call an entry (instead of 'Lv2009')

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after updating MikeTeX. It had something to do with that I had the files stored in a dropbox folder. After I copied everything to my desktop it worked again.